# JRXML subreport - Eliminating repeated header on the bottom

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I've got a problem when printing some PDF reports using JasperReports. These reports are basically a breakdown of all the sales made to a specific client over the course of the years.

I have one master report and subreport.

I take information from a DB, transform it using Java, and print the reports in PDF. The problem is, in some rare cases, some headers appear repeated at the bottom of each page:

[image]

In the image i need to remove the part inside the circle.
I am attaching the code for my report as below.
MasterReport

```
  > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.0  -->
    <!-- 2017-09-26T12:38:36 -->
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="scriptlet" pageWidth="1089" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="900" leftMargin="30" rightMargin="30" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30" isFloatColumnFooter="true" whenResourceMissingType="Empty" uuid="fc422c67-db33-4432-b0fe-9c5b6cbdc01c">
        <property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.Grid" value="false"/>
        <property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.SnapToGrid" value="false"/>
        <property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridWidth" value="10"/>
        <property name="com.jasperassistant.designer.GridHeight" value="10"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.create.bookmarks" value="false"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
        <parameter name="reportName" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="runDate" class="java.util.Date"/>
        <parameter name="month" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="year" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <parameter name="stations" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="contractType" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="cash" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="subReportParameter" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="innerSubReportParameter" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="pageHeader" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[pageHeader]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="pageHeaderTotal" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[pageHeader]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="monthlyAmortizationReport" class="java.util.List">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[monthlyAmortizationReport]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="monthlyAmortizationReportTotal" class="java.util.List">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[monthlyAmortizationReportTotal]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <group name="Group1">
            <groupHeader>
                <band height="605">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <frame borderSplitType="DrawBorders">
                        <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="2" width="1030" height="70" uuid="0e09fd68-d674-4ffe-8026-27560a2f6fb8"/>
                        <box>
                            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="35" y="21" width="100" height="15" uuid="091d6e12-3c88-4711-9278-c2990a483faa">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <box leftPadding="5"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="false"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <text><![CDATA[Station(s) Selected:]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement x="135" y="21" width="210" height="15" uuid="6e396536-4be3-4b2b-b938-14088da8e46e"/>
                            <box leftPadding="5"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="false"/>
                            </textElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{stations}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </frame>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="47" y="123" width="240" height="15" uuid="8007ea73-d590-42b2-a7e3-e12e0958fd92">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <box leftPadding="5"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="false"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Prepared By: ____________________________]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="47" y="178" width="240" height="15" uuid="9d1717cd-fe4d-4ca3-87b0-ba035b59c801">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <box leftPadding="5"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="false"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Reviewed By: ____________________________]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="690" y="123" width="180" height="15" uuid="0d0d7a65-73ef-48b5-b66d-0bf87d3f6f3a">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <box leftPadding="5"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="false"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Date: ________________________]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="690" y="178" width="180" height="15" uuid="dfbfed6d-0058-474b-be0a-b0f35998e4bb">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <box leftPadding="5"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="false"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Date: ________________________]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <break>
                        <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="600" width="550" height="1" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="cab606e6-99cd-454a-8749-2d5461d4f9a1"/>
                    </break>
                </band>
            </groupHeader>
        </group>
        <group name="pageHeader" isStartNewPage="true">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{pageHeader}]]></groupExpression>
            <groupHeader>
                <band height="1">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.FreeLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <subreport>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="1029" height="1" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#99CCFF" uuid="ec8271ee-6fb9-4c88-b730-b8031517400f">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <subreportParameter name="pageHeader">
                            <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{pageHeader}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                        </subreportParameter>
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource
                ($F{monthlyAmortizationReport})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subReportParameter}]]></subreportExpression>
                    </subreport>
                </band>
                <band height="1">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <subreport>
                        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="1029" height="1" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#99CCFF" uuid="ec8271ee-6fb9-4c88-b730-b8031517400f">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <subreportParameter name="pageHeader">
                            <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{pageHeader}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                        </subreportParameter>
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource
                ($F{monthlyAmortizationReportTotal})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                        <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{innerSubReportParameter}]]></subreportExpression>
                    </subreport>
                </band>
            </groupHeader>
        </group>
        <title>
            <band height="162" splitType="Stretch">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="35" y="0" width="70" height="15" uuid="d85beb8a-5178-43a7-8b24-5608250f088c">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box leftPadding="5"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Report Name:]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="105" y="0" width="552" height="15" uuid="3e8eb96b-1b5e-4f34-b1ec-f5770049d23e">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box leftPadding="5"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{reportName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="690" y="0" width="60" height="15" uuid="d85beb8a-5178-43a7-8b24-5608250f088c">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box leftPadding="5"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Run Date:]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="750" y="0" width="170" height="15" uuid="3e8eb96b-1b5e-4f34-b1ec-f5770049d23e"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{runDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="50" width="1029" height="70" uuid="6df8b9cc-b364-433c-b589-cacf4f0a679b">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="80" y="15" width="200" height="15" uuid="3e8eb96b-1b5e-4f34-b1ec-f5770049d23e">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <box leftPadding="5"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="false"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{month}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="35" y="45" width="45" height="15" uuid="d85beb8a-5178-43a7-8b24-5608250f088c">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <box leftPadding="5"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="false"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Year: ]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="80" y="45" width="200" height="15" uuid="3e8eb96b-1b5e-4f34-b1ec-f5770049d23e">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <box leftPadding="5"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="false"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{year}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="35" y="15" width="45" height="15" uuid="617febe3-cdac-4613-8986-b9dbd31a072d">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        </reportElement>
                        <box leftPadding="5"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                            <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="false"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Month:]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                </frame>
            </band>
        </title>
        <pageFooter>
            <band height="15">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="385" height="15" uuid="3e8eb96b-1b5e-4f34-b1ec-f5770049d23e">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box leftPadding="5"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="false" isUnderline="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{reportName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField evaluationTime="Page">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="386" y="0" width="150" height="15" uuid="e727b263-ae6c-4742-b102-64f0bc117b31">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER} + " o"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="536" y="0" width="171" height="15" uuid="e727b263-ae6c-4742-b102-64f0bc117b31">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["f " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement x="708" y="0" width="320" height="15" uuid="3e8eb96b-1b5e-4f34-b1ec-f5770049d23e">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box leftPadding="5"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{runDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </pageFooter>
    </jasperReport>
```

Comment: The problem is in your subreport (that is not in post), since there is space to print the columnHeader? or groupHeader? it will print it, if you are using groupHeader in subreport you can set a minHeight to print see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36740220/jrxml-eliminating-repeated-header-on-the-bottom

Comment: Thanks..It works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a group the generate the header, so you can use this attribute `minHeightToStartNewPage`, to determine how much space needs to remain otherwise break to new page.

```
<group name="DescriptionGroup" minHeightToStartNewPage="60">
```

or if you like to force it to always start on new page

```
<group name="DescriptionGroup" isStartNewPage="true">
```